# I don't know what's wrong with my code - Binary Tree

Tags: binary-tree

I'm now making a Binary Tree in C++, using friend class.

But, something is wrong, and I cannot know what should I change

```
template <class Type>
class BinaryTree{
public:

BinaryTree(){
    root = new BTNode<Type>();  
    currentNode = NULL;
}
~BinaryTree(){
    delete root, currentNode;
};

void insertItem(Type data){
    if(currentNode==NULL){
        Item = data;
        currentNode = root;
    }
    if(data<currentNode){
        if(currentNode->Left.is_empty()){
            currentNode->Left = new BTNode(data);
            currentNode = root;
            return;
        }
        else{
            currentNode = currentNode->Left;
            return insertItem(data);
        }
    }
    if(data>currentNode){
        if(currentNode->Right.is_empty()){
            currentNode->Right = new BTNode(data);
            currentNode = root;
            return;
        }
        else{
            currentNode = currentNode->Right;
            return insertItem(data);
        }
    }
    currentNode = root;
    return; 
}

void deleteItem(Type data){}
void is_empty(){
    if (this == NULL) return 1;
    else return 0;
}
void printInOrder(){                                
    if(!(currentNode->Left).is_empty()){
        currentNode = currentNode->Left;            
    }
}

private:
    BTNode<Type>* currentNode;
    BTNode<Type>* root;
};
```

and here the BTNode class that store the item of BinaryTree, and point the next Node:

```
template <class Type>
class BTNode{
public:

    friend class BinaryTree<Type>;

    BTNode(){}
    BTNode(Type data){
        Item = data;
    }
    ~BTNode(){}


private:
    Type Item;
    BTNode<Type> *Left, *Right;
};
```

The Binary Tree class's BTNode*root point the first Node, and currentNode will point the 'current node' while doing something like insertion or merging the nodes.

But when I compile, the Compiler Error C2143 occurs in the BinaryTree class,
here:

```
BTNode<Type>* root;
BTNode<Type>* currentNode;
```

The error says that there is no toke `;` in front of `<`
but I cannot know what is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears as though `BTNode` isn't correctly defined inside the `BinaryTree` class.  The compiler is not understanding that `BTNode` is a type.  Make sure you're including and linking the files correctly.